# Check if newer Version of AppxPackage is installed

Tags: powershell, uwp, windows-10-universal, appx

I wanted to know if can check if a newer Version of a Package is installed in Powershell.

I wanted to install the Package "Microsoft.VCLibs.x86.14.00.appx" via powershell.

I do that by the command: Add-AppxPackage .\Microsoft.VCLibs.x86.14.00.appx

but then I get the error: HRESULT: 0x80073D06, The Package could not be installed because a higher version f this package is already installed.

I checked with 
Get-AppxPackage * Microsoft.vclibs.14*
and yeah there is a higher Version.
So is there a way to access the version and compare them? and than decide to install the Package or not?

like a script where I get the installed packages via "Get-AppxPackage * Microsoft.vclibs.14*" und foreach the result and access the version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$FilePath = ".\Microsoft.VCLibs.x86.14.00.appx"
$FileVersion = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $FilePath).VersionInfo.ProductVersion
$HighestInstalledVersion = Get-AppxPackage -Name Microsoft.VCLibs* |
    Sort-Object -Property Version |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Version -Last 1

if ( $HighestInstalledVersion -lt $FileVersion ) {
    Add-AppxPackage $FilePath
}
```

Comment: For me $FileVersion = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $FilePath).VersionInfo.ProductVersion is Empty, Any idea why?